# I get import error after importing pyttsx3

Tags: python, pyttsx3

I've been making simple "voice assistant". I imported pyttx3 using `pip install pyttx3`(and yes i added `import pyttsx3` in the code), which successfully installed due to terminal outprint `Successfully installed pyttsx3-2.90` but then when i try to run the code i get `File "c:\Users\teeki\voiceassistant\va.py", line 1, in <module>  import pyttsx3 ImportError: No module named pyttsx3`

I already tried to lookup the problem, found some solutions, which didnt do anything for me. Some of things i tried:

1. reinstalling pyttsx3 with `pip uninstall pyttsx3` then installing it again
2. Installing it with `pipenv`
3. Changing python interpeter back and forth to `2.7`, `3.8`, `3.9`

EDIT:im using visual studio code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `py -m pip install pyttsx3`. Also, make sure that it is installed into your PATH.

If that doesn't work, try `pip3 install pyttsx3`.

Comment: Okay yes, i think it did the trick with `py -m pip install pyttsx3` as now i get same error for next import (speech_recognition as sr). I tried to install it the same way and it works. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a known issue for pyttsx3 version 2.90

You can fix it by simply uninstalling pyttsx3 and reinstalling version **2.71**

```
> pip uninstall pyttsx3

> pip install pyttsx3==2.71
```

Comment: I tried to do that, but still didn't work, after i tried `py -m pip install pyttsx3` and it works fine now. Thanks for helping me out